# attach image to UILabel not working

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, uilabel

I want to add right small icon to UILabel in iOS

this is the code I am using

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
        attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_list"];

        NSAttributedString *attachmentString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];

        NSMutableAttributedString *myString= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hi"];
        [myString appendAttributedString:attachmentString];

        cell.categoryTitle.attributedText = myString;
```

the result I got as following , the string and three dots, can any one tell me what is the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that icon size is very large and I solved it by resize the icon before add it to my label

so the working code as following :

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_ads.png”];

UIImage *myIcon = [self imageWithImage:image1 scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];

NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];

attachment.image = myIcon;

NSAttributedString *attachmentString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];

NSAttributedString *titleString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:test.catName];

NSMutableAttributedString *myString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@""];

[myString appendAttributedString:attachmentString];

[myString appendAttributedString:titleString];

cell.categoryTitle.attributedText = myString;
```